# How to freeze cabbage?

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, freezing

I have a glut of home-grown cabbage at the moment, more than I can eat before it goes bad! Is there any way to freeze cabbage (raw, cooked, whole, shredded...) or would I have to make gallons of cabbage soup / pickled cabbage?

Comment: Don't forget sauerkraut as a way to use/preserve cabbage.  (of course, you might count that as 'pickled cabbage', as I'm not familiar with that term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the type of cabbage, but I've had success with prepping as if I was about to boil, and then freeze on a dry cloth; Once frozen, transfer to an air tight freezer bag, and use as fast as is practical.

Comment: Hopefully this works, I'll be giving it a go soon!

Comment: @Rob I've found it works better with the fleshier varieties, such as a pointed cabbages. Savoy cabbage I tend to blanch, and make up as bubble & squeak, which can be kept in the fridge for a few days or frozen for a bit longer.

Answer (score 3):

I've never had particularly good experiences with freezing cabbage so that it's usable as a "fresh" vegetable afterwards. Personally I'd recommend going down the cabbage soup / picked cabbage route, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend the pickled cabbage sauerkraut method of saving cabbage.  Home made Choucroute garnie is wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

I have frozen fresh, chopped cabbage with success. I halved the head, cored, and cut into strips. Make sure it is dry and seal in a freezer bag, squeezing out the excess air. I would then add it to pastas and soups, never noticed a problem with taste or texture.

Answer (score 1):

Try food.com or just google freezer coleslaw.  It is crunchy and tastes almost as good as fresh. Try a little freeze overnight and taste, if you like it, freeze lots. It is handy to have for a quick salad.